# Why doesn't ellipsis work with table-cell when parent div sets width?

Tags: css

I am attempting to apply an ellipsis to a table cell, but set the cell width based on a parent div.

Consider the following example (JS fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/zncGk/):

HTML

```
<div class="mydiv">

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Hello Stack Overflow</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

CS

```
.mydiv{
    width:50px;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:block;

}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    console.log("width = " + $("td").width());
});
```

The output is: width = 132, and the ellipsis doesn't appear.

What am I missing here? The ellipsis works if I set the table-cell width directly, but I need to to be set by the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good and working but you have given a space in width like this `wi dith` in your demo. See this working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TDJVz/6/)

**Edit**

If you want to ellipsis make work you need to set table-layout to fixed and give your table to 100%.

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TDJVz/12/)

Comment: That was a typo; I want this to work with the div setting the width, not the cell-table

Comment: what you want to give ellipsis that must be defined with a width.

Comment: Thanks, is this possible without fixed tabel layout? I want different sized tabel-cells in my production version.

Comment: no, if you want your table layout to be auto then you need to define the cell width in pixel.